# Kubernetes Liveness probe & environment variables

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to figure this problem out where i need to Attach liveness probe to the container and restart after checking if environment USER is null or undefined.

Any advice on how to set this condition on a busybox container please?

Thanks for helping out a beginner.

Sincerely.
V

Comment: "after checking if environment USER is null or undefined" --- create an init container that checks the value, and if it's not of expected value simply returns with non-zero status code. This solution is prone to race conditions, but may suit you, depending on the actual context.

Comment: I'd also go with the approach @zerkms describes: the container's environment variables can't change, so it doesn't make sense to use a readiness probe to wait for it to become defined, or to use a liveness probe to restart if it becomes undefined.

Answer (score 1):

`[[ ! -z "$YOURVAR" ]]` will return false if $YOURVAR is not defined.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    test: liveness
  name: liveness-exec
spec:
  containers:
  - name: liveness
    image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
    args:
    - /bin/sh
    - -c
    - touch /tmp/healthy; sleep 30; rm -rf /tmp/healthy; sleep 600
    livenessProbe:
      exec:
        command:
        - /bin/bash
        - [[ ! -z "$var" ]]
      initialDelaySeconds: 5
      periodSeconds: 5
```